# Rehydrating state in an Angular 2 SPA upon application reload/bootstrap

Tags: angular, redux, indexeddb, ngrx

When it comes to **rehydrating application state** in an Angular 2 Single Page Application, one has -amongst others- two options:

1. Use some sort of local storage such as IndexedDB in order to store and fetch the state.
2. Use the Http backend in order to fetch the state.

I am trying to weigh the pros and con of one and the other of those options.

I rely on the ngrx librairies (see https://github.com/ngrx). I read about the meta reducers and ngrx/db which looks great but my main concern is which of the two above options to choose when the application is reloaded in the browser...

What are best practices as far as rehydrating state is concerned? What are the pros and cons of the two above options?

Comment: Currently the way I do it just chain up a couple of API calls depending on what  page the user is on which is not great. I am going to look into indexDB as that seems quite good. However will need to have a a look at support levels for features it uses or fallbacks for legacy browsers.

Comment: I do both: rehydrate from indexedDb for very fast initial bootstrap with potentially stale data, then refresh the state from the api to get fresh data.